# How can I force a Bandcamp iframe embed on my website to open in the parent window?

Tags: html, iframe

I've got some embedded iframe Bandcamp players on www.mangledmusic.net/releases. I set up our Bandcamp page to look like our website, which will have an image map of my sites page tabs. The link in the embedded players that takes you to bandcamp opens in a new tab every time. I have tried numerous solutions listed on this site, and none of them have worked. Is this possible? Obviously Bandcamp.com and my site are not the same domain. Thanks!

Comment: what is the desired behavior?

Comment: So as I understand it after looking at your page, the links are controlled by Bandcamp(third party) and the behavior is implemented by them so there is not much we can do. Also, even if you get it to load on same page, it might not look good.

Comment: Yes but the code is generated for me to copy and paste, so can't the code be edited to get the desired behavior from the links within it?

Comment: Here is the iFrame code that I am pasting into my site. I have tried target="_top" and other things, but I'm never sure if I'm putting them in the right place, and even when I was sure it didn't seem to work. Code:

Comment: <div align="center"><iframe style="border: 5; width: 700px; height: 120px;" src="https://bandcamp.com/EmbeddedPlayer/album=1364990113/size=large/bgcol=333333/linkcol=ffffff/tracklist=false/artwork=small/transparent=true/" seamless><a href="http://mangledmusiccollective.bandcamp.com/album/vol-1-jazzception">Vol.1: Jazzception by Mangled Music Collective</a></iframe>
</div>

Answer (score -1):

Are you able to edit the Bandcamp site?  Every link in the Bandcamp iFrame has the target set to _blank.  This tells the browser to open in a new window.

If you want the site to open in the same tab, you should use target="_top" in your links.

Comment: There is no "target" tag in the code though, and I've tried to manually add it in.

<div align="center"><iframe style="border: 5; width: 700px; height: 120px;" src="https://bandcamp.com/EmbeddedPlayer/album=1364990113/size=large/bgcol=333333/linkcol=ffffff/tracklist=false/artwork=small/transparent=true/" seamless><a href="http://mangledmusiccollective.bandcamp.com/album/vol-1-jazzception">Vol.1: Jazzception by Mangled Music Collective</a></iframe>
</div>

Comment: The target=_top has to be done on the Bandcamp, not in your iFrame tag.  I don't think you're going to get it to do what you need to do without making the change to Bandcamp.com.